# How to show errors in Laravel Website instead of 500 page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In a Laravel website, whenever PHP error occurs I see a customized screen of 500 Error instead of the error message. I tried to write error_reporting but still error cannot show.

How to fix this?

Comment: in `.env` -> `APP_DEBUG=true`   https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors Also you have not told anything about your environment, is it local? Shared hosting?

Comment: Did not find a reason why people do negative rating. The issue was with the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the cache issue. I have run these 2 commands and it got fixed.

config:cache
config:clear

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debug mode by setting `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file.

You should only do this for local development.